# On an orthogonal polynomial expansion of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials

I have some function that I am trying to study $ F(x) : [-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. I want write it in terms of a sum over Jacobi Polynomials
$$
F(x) = \sum_n f^{\alpha,\beta}_n P^{\alpha, \beta}_n(x)
$$
So far so good, but now I want to find the coefficients $f^{\alpha,\beta}_n$. No problem right? Well, the orthogonality conditions of the Jacobi polynomials is
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}w^{\alpha,\beta}(x)P^{\alpha,\beta}_n(x)P^{\alpha,\beta}_m(x) = N_{n}(\alpha,\beta)\delta_{nm}
$$
where $w^{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ is some non-trivial weight function, $N_n(\alpha,\beta)$ is a normalization coefficient, and $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker Delta function (only 1 if $n=m$).

So how would I go about computing the coefficients $f^{\alpha,\beta}_n$? My guess would be to redefine the Jacobi Polynomials such that
$$
P^{\alpha,\beta}_n(x) \rightarrow \tilde{P}^{\alpha,\beta}_n(x) = 
\sqrt{\frac{w^{\alpha,\beta}(x)}{N_n(\alpha,\beta)}}P^{\alpha,\beta}_n(x)
$$
As far as I know this is *all right*, but I really do not want to deal with square-roots of polynomials. The weight function is defined as
$$
w^{\alpha,\beta}(x) = (1-x)^{\alpha}(1+x)^{\beta}.
$$
This puts a restriction on what $\alpha$ can be since $F(x)$ maps $[-1,1]$ to the real number line.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You should not tamper with the weight function. Use the scalar product $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)}w(x) dx$, instead. The Jacobi polynomials are orthogonal (not orthonormal) with respect to this scalar product. So, by general theory, the coefficients are given by
$$
f_n^{\alpha, \beta}=\frac{\langle F, P^{\alpha, \beta}_n\rangle}{\langle P^{\alpha,\beta}_n, P^{\alpha,\beta}_n\rangle}.$$

Comment: I just want to make sure. Does this mean $\langle F, P_n^{\alpha,\beta} \rangle = \int_[-1,1]}F(x)P_n^{\alpha,\beta}w^{\alpha,\beta}(x)$? If I were working with, say, Legendre Polynomials, $\langle F, P_n^{\alpha,\beta} \rangle = \int_[-1,1]}F(x)P_n^{\alpha,\beta})$ since the weight function $w(x) = 1$. Is introducing $w(x)$ in the scalar product a consequence of "changing my basis"?

Comment: Unfortunately your LaTeX does not compile and it is hard to read your formulas. However, I think that they are OK. And yes, introducing a different weight in the scalar product is needed in order for the basis you want to be orthogonal.